# Onclick Expand Textbox Width

Tags: jquery, html

I want to use jQuery to expand the width of a input textbox during onclick.

For example, if the input has a default width of 100px, when the user clicks in it to type, it will expand to like 150px in width.

Is it possible to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Here's an [updated example](http://jsfiddle.net/DCjYA/1/) on jsfiddle that animates, and returns to the default size on blur.

For reference, see [jQuery Animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) docs.

Comment: Great. I'm not good with jQuery, so how would I make it return to its default width with it's not focused anymore? Also, instead of the sudden width change, would it be possible to do a smooth slideout?

Comment: Updated with the animation and blur handler.

Answer (score 8):

I'd like to build on @wsanville's example by removing the extra step on saving the original size. Animation also takes string values like '+=50' or '-=50' for increasing/decreasing the width.

[See in in action on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manu3569/t9sqN/)

```
$('#box').focus(function()
{
    $(this).animate({ width: '+=50' }, 'slow');
}).blur(function()
{
    $(this).animate({ width: '-=50' }, 'slow');
});
```

Answer (score 5):

I know this is a bit late to the party, but if anyone wants a pure CSS solution that uses the :focus attribute.

```
#textbox {
  width:100px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

#textbox:focus {
  width:150px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
```

Here's my jsFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/qo95uquv/

Tom

Answer (score 4):

Here a working example based on @wsanville's example with the requested delay. (Note I also added an effect to return it on loss of focus, you can remove that easily)

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/9SSg3/2/)

**edited the size of the textbox

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="text" id="tbText" size="30px"/>    

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#tbText').focus(function() {
            $('#tbText').css("width", "250px");
        });
        $('#tbText').blur(function() {
            $('#tbText').css("width", "150px");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

sure. Lets say you have

```
<input id="mytextbox" />
```

you can do

```
$("#mytextbox").focus(function(){
   $(this).width(150)
});
```