# How to call Jquery Function from textbox onclick-Primefaces

Tags: jquery, primefaces

I am trying to call below Jquery

```
 <h:outputScript target="head">
$('#box').focus(function()
        {
            /*to make this flexible, I'm storing the current width in an attribute*/
            $(this).attr('data-default', $(this).width());
            $(this).animate({ width: 150 }, 'fast');
        }).blur(function()
        {
            /* lookup the original width */
            var w = $(this).attr('data-default');
            $(this).animate({ width: w }, 'fast');
        });
</h:outputScript>
```

and **Primefaces** `textbox` code is below

```
<p:inputText style="margin-right:10px" id="box"/>
```

I am trying something like this [onclick-expand-textbox-width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6379745/onclick-expand-textbox-width)

My File is something like this

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
    <style>
.ui-menubar {
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    background: #3e9cbf  !important ;
}

.ui-menubar .ui-menuitem {
    width: auto;
    clear: none;
    margin-right: 3px;

}

.ui-menubar .ui-state-hover  {
    background-color: #E0ECF8 !important;
     color: #557FFF;
}
.ui-menuicon {
    background: url(images/vertical_line.jpg) no-repeat;
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;

}

 .ui-button-text {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
.ui-button-text-only .ui-button-text {
   font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #557FFF;
    width: 50px;
}
.ui-button.ui-state-hover  {
    background-color: #557FFF !important;
     color: white;
}
</style>

</h:head>
<h:body>
<h:outputScript target="head">
$('#box').focus(function()
        {
            /*to make this flexible, I'm storing the current width in an attribute*/
            $(this).attr('data-default', $(this).width());
            $(this).animate({ width: 150 }, 'fast');
        }).blur(function()
        {
            /* lookup the original width */
            var w = $(this).attr('data-default');
            $(this).animate({ width: w }, 'fast');
        });
</h:outputScript>
        <p:menubar styleClass="ui-menubar">
            <p:menuitem>
                <p:graphicImage value="/resources/images/qim_logo_inner.png"
                    style="height:37px;width:150px" />
            </p:menuitem>
            <p:menuitem value="Dashboard" style="color:white;"
                url="/welcome.xhtml" />
            <p:menuitem disabled="true" style="color:white;" value="|" />
            <p:menuitem value="Questions" url="/core/search.xhtml"
                style="color:white;" />
            <p:menuitem value="|" disabled="true" style="color: white;" />
            <p:menuitem value="Members" url="#" style="color:white;" />
            <p:menuitem value="|" disabled="true" style="color: white;" />
            <p:menuitem value="Technologies" url="#" style="color:white;" />
            <p:menuitem value="|" disabled="true" style="color: white;" />
            <p:menuitem value="Ask a Question" url="/core/ask_question.xhtml"
                style="color:white;" />

            <f:facet name="options">
                <p:inputText style="margin-right:10px" id="box"/>
                <p:commandButton type="button" value="Search" 
                    url="/core/search.xhtml" />
            </f:facet>
        </p:menubar>


</h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: Looks like your code works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/mRUE7/. I did change the initial width of the text box, since it was pretty close to 150px and I didn't notice a change when focusing it. Try looking at the rendered html and javascript, to make sure primefaces generated what you expect.

Comment: It mean here issue with code

Answer (score 2):

The thing is, that your `id="box"` won't come out as an HTML id addressable by `#box`. It will be rendered as `id="myForm:box"`. If you got that, you have to make your jQuery selector compatible because the colon is already a reserved char in jQuery selector syntax. So you have to escape the selector as follows `$('#myForm\\:box').focus(...)`.

```
<h:body>
  <h:form id="myForm">
    ...
      <p:inputText style="margin-right:10px" id="box"/>
    ...
  </h:form>
</h:body>
```

Comment: CAN YOU ELOBRATE BIT MORE

Comment: To do this, I need mor input from your side. How does your page structure looks like and what is your `h:form` id. If it has none, add one. Best you update your questions code block to cover this.

Comment: '<h:form>' ID IS NONE RIGHT NOW and i am using template here

Comment: So, you have to give your form an ID because otherwise JSF will always generate a dynamic one. With a dynamic one, you are not able to address the textbox as you want to. I'll add a simple code snippet to my answer but more I can't do. The rest is up to you.

Comment: k but it it is template header page for me and in main template i am using h:form if i will use h:form in this page as well it will nested h:form in pages

Comment: You are correct, nested forms are a bad idea. So just surround your `</p:menubar>` and not the whole body.

Comment: yes right if i will surround the '<p:menuBar/>' it will still nested form for main template because this a small part of main template and main template have 'h:form' declared i think in main template i have to give id and then use according to your solution

Comment: This should work. Give it a try and don't forget to accept the answer ;-)

Comment: To get it done, you should reduce your code to the minimum. just one Page, just your form and textbox, no template. Seems there is another problem. The solution described above works if the environment is correct.

Comment: @JavaProgrammer hey, any luck until now?