# expand search input bar on click bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Well, I´m trying to do a search input expands on click in my button class="expand".
I already have this working but it have two bugs at least.
The first is when I click in the button to expand de input, the input expands but then contract right away. I dont understand why this is happening.
The second bug is wherever I click on my page the input expands and contracts right away. I think is to be using `$('html').click(function()` but I´m not see other way to do this. 
Can you give a little help?

**My jQuery:**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">        
        $(function() {
            $('button.expand').click(function() {
                $('#test').width(0).show().animate({width: 180}, 500);
            });
            $('html').click(function() {
            $('#test').width(180).show().animate({width: 0}, 500);
        });
        });  
    </script>
```

**My Html:**

```
<nav id="menu">
        <ul>

            <li><a href="Home.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="About.html">About</a></li>


            <li>
                  <div id="search-container">
        <span id="search" >
             <form  name="form1" >
                <input id="test" type="search" placeholder="Search..." required="required" onfocus="if(this.placeholder == 'Search...') {this.placeholder=''}" onblur="if(this.placeholder == ''){this.placeholder ='Search...'}" />
                <button class="expand" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
             </form>
        </span> 
    </div>
            </li>
           </ul>
    </nav>
```

**My css:**
CSS:

```
 .form-container input {display:none;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about controlling the state of `#test` visibility?

```
$(function() {
    $('button.expand').click(function() {
        $('#test').width(0).show().animate({width: 180}, 500);
        $('#test').addClass("visible");
    });
    $('html').click(function() {
        if($('#test').hasClass("visible")){
            $('#test').width(180).show().animate({width: 0}, 500).removeClass("visible");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you. That code makes sense and seems a good solution. I never used if statement in jQuery before. Is given me an error in the line of if statement I thought it might be of braces but is not. I searched for the hasClass method and its writtent correct. Where might be the error?

Comment: It was just a typo, fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look to [jQuery Animate docs](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) and to stackoverflow's answer [Onclick Expand Textbox Width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6379745/onclick-expand-textbox-width). Hope this help you.